# How to structure large memcache datasets

Tags: python, memcached

We are using Django 1.4 w/ Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 13.04 - although this question is probably independent of this information.

I have a requirement where we hit a very slow API for our website.  As a result our pages tend to load between 3-6 seconds.  Our data shows that we have nearly 0% retention rate after 5 seconds.  As a result I'm implementing a memcache solution for the data we pull from the 3rd party API - which is known to update every 4 hours.

My question deals with the "best practice" for handling memcache datasets.  We generally pull a portion of the complete dataset for any given request.  The entire dataset takes about 20 minutes to pull down - it's quite large.

I'd like to stay away from increasing the maximum memcache unit size (64 MB) if I can.  To this end it seemed reasonable to slice the data into logical units.  To provide motivation for this question I should mention that ultimately I will be JSONifying the data.  To provide an example:

```
{Layer1:
    Layer2: {
        Layer3: {
            Layer4: {
                'data1': some_data,
                'data2': some_more_data,
                'data3': even_more_data,
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where there are multiple data segments for each layer (I believe the data embeds between 4 and 6 layers).

I was thinking it would be a good idea to store at the `Layer1` level, which should always be below the 64 MB limit.  Another option is to store at the individual data level and key as `Layer1-Layer2-Layer3-Layer4`...not exactly elegant but proven to work in our system.

The purpose of this question is primarily for opinion purposes based on your experience with caching information.  Ultimately our needs require information within `Layer1` level data at a time.

If there is a good reason to move away from caching at `Layer1` level please let me know.

Thanks in advance for your opinions.

EDIT1:

Based on the response from Brent Washburne I feel elaboration might be necessary.  I handle the backend of a large system that manages 1000s of front-end webpages (landing pages).  Each webpage will request details from this dataset.  The user will enter search parameters and the front-end must query the dataset for information to dynamically populate the results.

Fortunately our landing pages reside on a server on the same intranet as our backend server - so requests are very fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the question "should I store a few large chunks of data or many small chunks of data?"  Without knowing more about your layering scheme, I'd say go with the large chunks.  Each memcache request is a network request, and you can minimize traffic by minimizing requests.

Another option is to cache the web pages on your server.  After you pull the data (every four hours, you say), write the HTML pages from the data and store them in your web folder.  Then your static pages will be served in no time and you won't need a memcache server.

Comment: Thank you for the input.  How large would you recommend until you start slicing smaller chunks?  I'm currently at the point where `Layer1` data is approaching 30MB a piece (and there are 100s of `Layer1` instances).  To provide more details - this implementation is purely backend.  The frontend is handled elsewhere so creating HTML pages for this data is not applicable.

Comment: It's still hard to say what the right size is.  Your network speed is a big factor, along with memcache (CPU + memory) speed.  Set up a memcache test to perform multiple queries in parallel at various chunk sizes.  At some point, the throughput will fall off as one bottleneck becomes saturated.  Then pack your query results into the optimal chunk size.